# Add more than one tile layers to <Mapcontainer> in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I want to add more than one tilelayers to mapcontainer. I am not able to accomplish that. I have one tilelayer like this

```
const magnifiedTiles = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
```

and another one here:

```
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
 return (
<>
         <MapContainer center={center} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true} style={{height: 'calc(100% - 30px)'}}>
 <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' 
    /> 

</>)
}
```

I can either get a map reference from map container and use like `magnifiedTiles.addTo(<map>)`but I dont know how to get the map reference. Other option is `addLayer()`. However, I am not able to access it with from L.Tilelayer.

I know it leaflet it was as simple as getting map reference and using `map.addLayer()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the map reference via a ref in react-leaflet v.4.x

```
const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={zoom}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        ref={setMap}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
```

and then use a useEffect to add any layer you want.

```
useEffect(()=> {
if (!map) return ;

map.addLayer(...);
},[])
```

**Edit after you added the typescript tag:**
Same as before only thing that changes you should install @types/react-leaflet and declare the map ref type.

```
import { Map as MapProp, tileLayer } from "leaflet";
...
const streets = tileLayer(
  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}",
  {
    attribution:
      '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken:
      ...
  }
);
```

[Source for streets layer that includes token](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371901/function-with-map-addlayer-and-map-removelayer-not-working)

```
const [map, setMap] = useState<MapProp | null>(null);

...
useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    map.addLayer(streets);
  }, [map]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-more-than-one-tile-layers-to-mapcontainer-in-react-leaflet-v-4-x-h1zx48)

Comment: On addLayer, it gives error 'Property 'addLayer' does not exist on type 'never' and on ref in MapContainer , it gives error  "Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Map> | undefined'.
  Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '(instance: Map | null) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'value' and 'instance' are incompatible.
      Type 'Map | null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'."

Comment: Sorry but your question is for javascript not for typescript.

Comment: do you have it implemented somewhere?

Comment: I could add a demo in js

Comment: I am working on typescript. Sorry, I can add a tag to the question.